# IE10 on Windows 7: SVG Scrolling too far when inside a div

Tags: javascript, windows-7, svg, internet-explorer-10

I am doing an SVG drawing inside a DIV. The drawing is larger than the DIV, so scrolling becomes active. I am testing this on my computer, which has IE10 and Windows 7. IE10 seems to scroll the SVG drawing past it's end point. IE9, Chrome and Firefox does not do this. The code below reproduces the issue.

If you use this to create an html page and run it in Chrome, you should see a line from the top left to the bottom right as you scroll. At the extreme right of scrolling, the line stops EXACTLY at the right hand side of the yellow-green SVG element, with a red line indicating the limit..

However, with IE10 on my Windows 7 machine, the line stops somewhat to the left of the end. This "somewhat" gets greater as the size of the SVG drawing increases. It seems like IE scrolls the SVG drawing past its right limit. This causes havoc for me when trying to get click locations and converting this back to real coordinates.

I posted this question previously thinking the problem is in both IE9 and IE10, but since then I isolated it to IE10. I also posted in in another forum (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/0d4ef7dd-7e1c-4a09-a483-2760367a2e84), and someone came back saying they do not see the same problem. So it may have something to do with compatibility view. However, if I press F12 in IE while testing, I see "Browser Mode: IE10, Document mode: Standards"

Help is greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>IE SVG SCroll Problem</title>        
    <META http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE, NO-STORE" />               
</head>
<body onload="draw()">
   <div style="position:absolute; left:100px; top:50px; width:500px; height: 300px; background-color:wheat;">
   <div id="plotRect" style="position:relative; left:40px; top:25px; width:400px; height:240px; 
background-color:antiquewhite; border:1px solid black; overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden;">
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

function draw() {

    //plotRect is the inner div that holds the SVG drawing. We want to scroll on this.
    var plotRect = document.getElementById("plotRect");

    //Add SVG viewbox element to hold the svg drawing
    var width = 5800;   //container div is only 400px wide, so this will cause scrollbar to show
    var height = 240;   //same as container div

    var svg = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg");
    svg.setAttribute("id", "test");
    svg.setAttribute("version", "1.2");        
    svg.setAttribute("width", width);
    svg.setAttribute("height", height);
    svg.setAttribute("style", "background-color:yellowgreen; overflow:hidden");
    svg.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "none");
    plotRect.appendChild(svg);

    //now draw a line from top left corner to bottom right corner
    var x1 = 0;
    var y1 = 0;
    var x2 = width;  //note this width is same as the viewbox width
    var y2 = 220;

    //add the line
    var l = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'line');
    l.setAttribute("x1", x1);
    l.setAttribute("y1", y1);
    l.setAttribute("x2", x2);
    l.setAttribute("y2", y2);
    l.setAttribute("stroke-width", 3);
    l.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
    svg.appendChild(l);

    var l1 = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'line');
    l1.setAttribute("x1", x2);
    l1.setAttribute("y1", y1);
    l1.setAttribute("x2", x2);
    l1.setAttribute("y2", y2);
    l1.setAttribute("stroke-width", 3);
    l1.setAttribute("stroke", "red");
    svg.appendChild(l1);

}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, with SVG on IE10 scrolling beyond the content.
I fixed it by simply adding the following to my stylesheet or the equivalent in a style attribute.

```
svg {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This took me hours to track down but with a single rule in my default stylesheet, all the problems are gone.

It seems that IE9 & 10 are the only browsers that support overflow on SVG objects although IE9 defaults to hidden. It would appear that IE10 is the one that fits with the specs as overflow is meant to default to visible on all objects in HTML.

Still not sure why the svg content doesn't fit inside the svg object however...

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solved my IE11 issue with SVG as well.  Here's something REALLY stupid, I tracked it down to a single <text> element that was NOWHERE near the edge of the screen or any other div border.  ANY SVG <text> node in the document caused scroll bars to appear.  Of course, Chrome, FF and Safari in all other desktop and devices worked FINE.  Tested on Win7, iPad (original and Air), and a Nexus 7 Android tablet.  Validated code on W3C as well. This is MSIE bug.  But of course we knew that, right?  IE 11, new number, same piece of s^%t.